# Can I expect this value to be cached by a JavaScript engine?

Tags: javascript, optimization, interpreter

Inside a function I have the lines

```
     var deal_date = new Date(deal.Created),
          cur_date = new Date(), 
   num_days_passed = Math.floor((cur_date - deal_date) / (1000*60*60*24));
```

and I'm wondering whether, since it's in a function, the value of the computation `1000*60*60*24` will be cached by the JavaScript engine. Because otherwise I have to get rid of the magic number by defining some constant

```
window.SECONDS_PER_DAY = 1000*60*60*24;
```

and over time it gets laborious to create all this extra code, especially when `1000*60*60*24` is in fact more descriptive to someone reading the code (unless they're an idiot).

Comment: Is this question a result of a direct problem you've encountered rather than theory?

Comment: It's a question of compiler optimization - certainly the closure compiler from Google converts the constant expression `1000*60*60*24` to `864E5` when minifying the code. I would expect modern compilers to do the same.